# How to run a SQL batch within an Azure runbook?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, cloud, azure-automation

I need to execute a batch to perform some maintenance tasks in my database but all the examples on Azure Automation I see are dealing with [a single SQL command](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-use-a-SQL-Command-be77f9d2).

How do I do it if creating an SP is not an option? I think I need to either somehow embed my *script.sql* file into a runbook script or reference it (like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx), for example)?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the .sql file in Azure Blob Storage, and within the runbook download the .sql file, read its contents, and pass that to the SqlCommand object.

Something like:

```
try {
    # Connect to Azure using service principal auth
    $ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $AzureConnectionAssetName         

    Write-Output "Logging in to Azure..."

    $Null = Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if(!$ServicePrincipalConnection) {
        throw "Connection $AzureConnectionAssetName not found."
    }
    else {
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$Path = "C:\abc.sql"
Set-AzureRmCurrentStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageAccountName

Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $Container -Blob $Blob -Destination $Path
$Content = Get-Content $Path
$Cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Content, $Conn)
```